# How to force on Table TD to fully occupy the height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, sass

I want to build the following layout, which contain a table with three cells and 2 columns:-

[image]

Currently i have the following code:-

```
<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2"><a class="singleNews_4011fad0" href="https://.sharepoint.com/sites/SovDemo/SitePages/Why-I-donate-to-charities.aspx"><div class="singleNews__image_4011fad0" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://.sharepoint.com/sites/SovDemo/SiteAssets/1one.jpg&quot;);"></div>
<div class="singleNews__content_4011fad0"><div class="singleNews__content__info_4011fad0">
<span class="singleNews__content__info__label_4011fad0">Featured News</span>
<span class="singleNews__content__info__date_4011fad0">11-11-2021</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="singleNews__content_4011fad0"><div class="singleNews__content__info_4011fad0">
<h2 class="singleNews__content__info__title__featured_4011fad0">Contoso employee giving program</h2>
<div class="singleNews__content__info__reactions_4011fad0">
<span class="singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes_4011fad0">
<i data-icon-name="Like" aria-hidden="true" class="root-168"></i>22</span>
<span class="singleNews__content__info__reactions__comments_4011fad0">
<i data-icon-name="ActionCenter" aria-hidden="true" class="root-168"></i>2332
</span>
</div></div></div></a>
</td>
<td rowspan="1">
<a class="singleNews_4011fad0" href="https://.sharepoint.com/sites/SovDemo/SitePages/Replacing-What-Is-Used.aspx"><div class="singleNews__image_4011fad0" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://.sharepoint.com/sites/SovDemo/SiteAssets/2two.jpg&quot;);"></div>
<div class="singleNews__content_4011fad0"><div class="singleNews__content__info_4011fad0"><span class="singleNews__content__info__label_4011fad0">Coorporate News</span>
<span class="singleNews__content__info__date_4011fad0">11-11-2021</span>
</div></div>
<div class="singleNews__content_4011fad0"><div class="singleNews__content__info_4011fad0"><h2 class="singleNews__content__info__title_4011fad0">Replacing What Is Used</h2><div class="singleNews__content__info__reactions_4011fad0"><span class="singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes_4011fad0">
<i data-icon-name="Like" aria-hidden="true" class="root-168"></i>22</span>
<span class="singleNews__content__info__reactions__comments_4011fad0">
<i data-icon-name="ActionCenter" aria-hidden="true" class="root-168"></i>2332</span></div></div></div></a></td></tr><tr><td rowspan="1">
<a class="singleNews_4011fad0" href="https://.sharepoint.com/sites/SovDemo/SitePages/A-Task-Force-for-Change.aspx"><div class="singleNews__image_4011fad0" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://.sharepoint.com/sites/SovDemo/SiteAssets/3three.jpg&quot;);"></div><div class="singleNews__content_4011fad0"><div class="singleNews__content__info_4011fad0"><span class="singleNews__content__info__label_4011fad0">People News</span><span class="singleNews__content__info__date_4011fad0">11-11-2021</span></div></div><div class="singleNews__content_4011fad0"><div class="singleNews__content__info_4011fad0"><h2 class="singleNews__content__info__title_4011fad0">A Task Force for Change</h2><div class="singleNews__content__info__reactions_4011fad0"><span class="singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes_4011fad0"><i data-icon-name="Like" aria-hidden="true" class="root-168"></i>22</span><span class="singleNews__content__info__reactions__comments_4011fad0"><i data-icon-name="ActionCenter" aria-hidden="true" class="root-168"></i>2332</span></div></div></div></a></td></tr>
</table>
```

and the following .scss file:-

```
@import '~office-ui-fabric-react/dist/sass/References.scss';
@import '../../../../assets/global.module';

.featured {
  flex: 2;
}

.secondary {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

.singleNews {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: $font-family;
  font-size: $font-size;
  font-weight: $regular-font-weight;

  &__image {
    padding: 5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    &.featured {
      height: 75%;
    }
  }

  &__content {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: $white;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid $medium-silver;
    border-top: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    &.featured {
      height: 25%;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    &__info {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: $regular-font-weight;
      color: $primary-font-color;

      &__title {
        font-size: 16px; //22px mob
        font-weight: $semiBold-font-weight;
        color: $primary-font-color;
        max-width: 290px;
        min-width: 135px;
        margin: 15px 0 0;
        word-break: break-word;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        display: -webkit-box;
        line-height: 23px; /* fallback */
        max-height: 46px; /* fallback */
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

        &__featured {
          font-size: 22px; //2.33 mobile
          font-weight: $semiBold-font-weight;
          max-width: 230px;
          margin: 15px 0 0;
        }
        &__first {
          font-size: 1.83em; //2.33 mobile
          font-weight: $semiBold-font-weight;
          max-width: 230px;
          margin: 15px 0 0;
        }
        
      }
      

      &__date,
      &__label {
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }

      &__reactions {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-self: flex-end;
        margin-bottom: 5px;

        &__likes {
          margin-right: 10px;
        }

        &__likes > i,
        &__comments > i {
          margin-right: 5px;
        }
      }
    }
  }


  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    &__content {
      &__info {
        &__title {
          max-width: 230px;

          &__featured {
            font-size: 1.83em; //22px mob
            min-width: 380px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the second .scss:-

```
@import '~office-ui-fabric-react/dist/sass/References.scss';
@import '../../../assets/global.module';

.featureNews {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: $font-family;
  font-size: $font-size;
  font-weight: $regular-font-weight;

  & > * {
    flex: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .featureNews {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

The above is working well, but I only issue I am facing is: how can I expand the first box (cell) to fully occupy the vertical space, as per the arrows I added to the picture?

Comment: Do you have to use a Table? You can use grid instead.

Comment: @Imanpal Singh i do not have any specific requirement on the layout components, can you provide an example of a grid which will work for me case?